# How can I extract data from multiple nested expand from ODATA using OLINGO?

Tags: java, apache, nested, odata, olingo

I am having a problem figuring out as to how I can extract the data that I am getting from the uri that I've build from apache olingo. Extracting data from the $expand works with this syntax.

uri: odata/PropertyOrigin?$expand=Property1($select=Field1);$expand=Property2($select=Field1ofProperty2))

```
/* JSON -> 
PropertyOrigin -> 
Field1Origin,
Field2Origin,   
NavigationProperty1 -> 
Field1,
Field2,
Field3,
NavigationProperty2 ->
NavigationField1ofProperty2 <- the one I am trying to extract */

ClientEntity ce = csi.next();
String ExtractData1 = ce.getProperty("Property1").getComplexValue().get("Field1").getValue().toString();
```

But, when I am trying to get the data from the second $expand, I get a object null reference, because it is not hitting the right property that I am trying to interact with.

```
ClientEntity ce = csi.next();
String ExtractData2 = ce.getProperty("NavigationProperty1").getComplexValue().get("NavigationProperty2").getComplexValue().get("Field1ofNavigationProperty2").getValue().toString();
```

Note:
NavigationProperty2 is a Collection

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out:

```
 ClientEntity ce = csi.next();
 ClientCollectionValue<ClientValue> ccv = ce.getProperty("NavigationProperty1")
                                 .getComplexValue()
                                 .get("NavigationProperty2")
                                 .getCollectionValue();

 Iterator<ClientValue> ite = ccv.iterator();
 ClientValue cv = ite.next();
 String extractData3 = cer.asComplex().get("Field1ofNavigationProperty2").getValue().toString();
```

Description: Since the NavigationProperty2 is a collection, I figured I have to use the getcollectionvalue, instead of using getvalue or getcomplexvalue, after that I placed it on the iterator then started getting the data.